# Change Capture SQL

Tags: sql

Why change tracking captures the update operation, when same update command is issued again.
`Update Table Set column1 = value where id=1`

If I execute this command again and again, **Change capture** captures each update operation even though column1's value is not changed.
Any solution to log only update when a column value is changed.

Comment: Use an update trigger?

Comment: It is hard to understand understand your question, please try to be more explicit

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you talking about?

Comment: I am using ChangeTable feature of SQL Server to know if any changes are made to any row of a table.                              
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/changetable-transact-sql                                                                            I expect when i execute this command UPDATE tablename SET column1 = value WHERE colm2 = 1 , this change is recorded by ChangeTable, I do results in ChangeTable , but when i issue same update without changing anything, again i get results in ChangeTable function.